# flutter vscode shows install extension message on run start debugging

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Every time I want to start Flutter App in debugging, via Run -> Start debugging from **VScode** top menu,
**Vscode** shows a message **Install Extension**

[image]

kindly guide how to fix this (via `flutter run` it works fine, does not gives any error or message)

Comment: Does this occur if you disable all extensions except the Dart and Flutter extension? If so, please file an issue at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code so I can take a look. Thanks!

Comment: All extensions are active, all including Dart and Flutter extensions are not made disable

Comment: @JaveedIshaq Were you able to solve this ,facing the same problem right now

Comment: I am able to run debug by => first open 'main.dart' in the editor (make its code visible), then click on the Play icon(Run and Debug) in the left side pan of vscode.

the run=>start debugging still gives error